# LightNCandy Handlebars: How to use 'this' in static php helper method

Tags: php, handlebars.js

I'm using [lightncandy](https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy) to render my handlebars-templates server-side and have the following issue with a helper. This is the code in js:

```
valOrIcon: function(prop) {
  return ((typeof this[prop] !== 'undefined') && this[prop] !== null) ? this[prop] : unknown;
},
```

How do I convert this into proper PHP code? Since my helper methods are all static methods in my HandlebarsHelper.php class, I've got no clue how to reference this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'hbhelpers' => Array(
  'valOrIcon' => function($prop, $options) {
    return isset($options['_this'][$prop]) ? $options['_this'][$prop] : 'unknown';
  },
  ...
)
```

require lightncandy v0.20 or higher.